# Rearranging the formula $z = \frac{1-x}{1-yx}$ for $x$ where $0<y<1 ; 0<x<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm an astronomer and therefore only really use basic algebra, so I understand this is probably a stupidly simple question...

Anyway - the equation $z = \dfrac{1-x}{1-yx}$ has a [very bizarre form](https://www.google.fr/search?safe=off&ei=2jlrWsqMLdL0kwWohYz4Bw&q=graph%20%281-x%29%2F%281-y*x%29&oq=graph%20%281-x%29%2F%281-y*x%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l4.722.870.0.1028.2.2.0.0.0.0.90.169.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.169....0.gMwGopXWmu8) because of its numerous $\dfrac{1}{x}$ asymptotes. However, where $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $1$ (in my case these are ratios - the flux ratio and depth), there is a continuous real solution, and therefore each $x$ & $y$ give a unique $z$ point, and vice-versa each $y$ & $z$ point give a unique $x.$

So it should be possible to rearrange for $x$, such that $x = f(y,z)$. However, I have been unable to find a solution...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: asymptote.......

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \begin{align}
z &= \dfrac{1-x}{1-yx} \\ z(1-yx) &= 1-x \\ z - zyx &= 1-x \\ x - zyx &= 1-z \\ x(1-zy) &= 1-z \\ x &= \dfrac{1-z}{1-zy}
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$z=\frac{1-x}{1-xy} \iff z-zxy=1-x\iff x-zxy=1-z\iff x(1-zy)=1-z \\\iff x=\frac{1-z}{1-zy}$$